# Show that $ \mu=R'(0) $

Tags: statistics

Let the moment-generating function $M(t)$ of $X$ exist for $ -h \lt t\lt h$. Consider the function $ R(t)=ln M(t)$. The first two derivative of $R(t)$ are,

$ R'(t)=\frac {M'(t)}{M(t)}$ and $R''(t)=\frac{M(t)M''(t)-[M'(t)]^2}{[M(t)]^2}$

Setting t=0, show that

a) $\mu =R'(0)$

b) $\sigma ^2=R''(0) $

My attempt:

All I know is that $\mu=M'(0)$ and $\sigma^2=M''(0)-[M'(0)]^2$

So, I guess I have to show somehow that $M'(0)=\frac {M'(t)}{M(t)}$ and $M''(0)-[M'(0)]^2=\frac{M(t)M''(t)-[M'(t)]^2}{[M(t)]^2}$

I also know that $ R(t)=log _e M(t)$, which is the same as $e^{R(t)}=M(t)$

From here, I don't know where to proceed. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $M(0)=1$  And that's it.

Comment: how do you know that? This probably is a dumb question.

Comment: $E(e^{tX})$ plug $t=0$ so you get $E(1)=1=M(0).$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** Note that $M(0)=1$, and plug in $0$ to $R'(t)$, $R''(t)$.

Comment: how did you know that M(0)=1?

Comment: @Lily $M(t)=E(e^{tX})$ so $M(0)=...$